# Searching lines after a particular line in perl

Tags: perl

I have a logfile and there I am trying to store all the line once I found `This has happened due to.` and then new line starts.

So basically the log looks like this

```
Bla bla bla bla....This has happened due to.

ABC

DEF

GHI

JKL
```

can you please help me to match the paatern once I found the line "This has happened due to."

Answer (score 4):

```
while (<>) {
  next unless /This has happened due to/;
  while (<>) {
    # Process lines
  }
  last;
}
```

Comment: please, change your answer to "file input"

Comment: @loldop I prefer to write scripts that process stdin, unless there's some reason not to. He can always adapt this to his specific needs.

Comment: In my test this causes the interpreter to hang forever.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine if I redirected input. But if I read from the terminal, I had to type Ctl-D twice, because both loops were checking for EOF. So I've added the "last;" statement to break out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<>) {
    last if /This has happened due to/;
}

while (<>) {
    print; # do smth with the line
}
```

Save the script to a file and make it executable. Then run like `./script.pl logfile`